# Order by null first and then in descending order

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I have LINQ Script where group by key possibly null. I got the result correctly and now I want to order by first null and then in descending order. because the group by key can be null so I cannot check as .hasValue!

In following approach I am getting null exception as it seems I am not handling null in order correctly?

```
var v25 = (from transaction in filteredTransactions
       join schedule in schedules on
       new { siteId = transaction.LoginSiteID, startDate = transaction.LoginDateTime.Date, payrollNumber = transaction.PayrollNumber } equals
       new { siteId = schedule.SiteId, startDate = schedule.StartTime.Value.Date, payrollNumber = schedule.PayrollNumber }
          into ezi_s_t
       from scheduleTransactions in ezi_s_t.DefaultIfEmpty()
       group transaction by scheduleTransactions into groupedScheduleTransactions
       select new
       {
           Schedule = groupedScheduleTransactions.Key,
           Transactions = groupedScheduleTransactions.ToList()
       }
     )
     .OrderBy(x=> x.Schedule == null? null : x.Schedule.EziScheduleId)
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Is [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/10352740) helpful?

Comment: To prevent comparing `null` with other types, simply assign Key some small value of same type as `EziScheduleId` so it will be first when ordering by it

Comment: I added a demo to my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `OrderByDescending()` when it is null and then use `ThenByDescending()`

```
.OrderByDescending(x=> x.Schedule == null)
.ThenByDescending(x => x.Schedule?.EziScheduleId);
```

And about your comment, the reason you are getting `System.NullReferenceException` error is because if `Schedule` is null, you cannot access its properties (as there is none) so you need to change `x.Schedule.EziScheduleId` to `x.Schedule?.EziScheduleId`

Live [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i093VK)

Comment: Suggested edit: EziScheduleId should be used to search in `Ascending` order, so `ThenBy` should be used

Comment: @TomasChabada but the OP says "**and then in descending order**", however I was just presenting the solution, that one OP can decide

Comment: you are right, I got confused by reading OP's code

Comment: Yes you are right. actually after you said it, I took a look at the code, and changed my answer, and then I remembered it was mentioned in the question.

Comment: I am still getting error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

<>f__AnonymousType22<<Transactions>j__TPar, <Schedule>j__TPar>.Schedule.get returned null.